# Unattended upgrades finds nothing when run manually

Tags: apt, cron, unattended-upgrades

When run manually, `sudo unattended-upgrade` finds nothing to upgrade:

```
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

But doing `sudo apt update` beforehand miraculously changes the situation:

```
Packages that will be upgraded: ...
...
All upgrades installed
```

The config in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` contains `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";` as it should do. This is presumably only used by `cron`, which could explain the outdated package list.

Also, the manpage for `unattended-upgrade` says:

> This script is the backend for the APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade option and designed to be run from cron (e.g. via /etc/cron.daily/apt)

Is `unattended-upgrades` is entirely dependent on `cron`, and if so does that mean it should not be run from a script?

**Edit: TLDR.** Running `unattended-upgrades` outside `cron`, in a shell, does not upgrade anything, even though the config looks right. Apparently this is because a separate `cron` job is responsible for updating the packages list. Is this behavior correct?

Comment: Agree completely, which is why there is only one question asked. It is the one right at the end, and the only phrase that has a question mark on it.

Comment: 18 LTS. So most recent one, everything as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that a successful `unattended-upgrade` is indeed dependent on a recent update of the package lists (equivalent to `apt update`). It relies on this being done either by `cron` (check `/etc/cron.daily/`, `/etc/cron.d/`) or more likely a `systemd` timer (do `sudo systemctl list-timers`).

This package will **not** itself trigger the update, nor will it check that the package lists are up to date. If they are not, it will just write to its log that there is nothing to install.

Answer (score 1):

**Partially correct**

Unattended-upgrades in 16.04 and older did indeed rely upon cron to trigger the combined update/upgrade service.

However, that changed: 18.04 uses systemd timers instead of cron. The timers for update and upgrade are independent, and may run many hours apart. This is the most likely (and expected) cause for packages miraculously appearing - they were likely uploaded/mirrored after the previous update.

You can run the `unattended-upgrades` command from the a shell prompt, and it will do *exactly* the same job as if triggered by cron (16.04 and older) or systemd timer (18.04 and newer).

Since it's all controlled by systemd, you can use any trigger you want to start daily update and upgrade - you're not restricted to using the built-in timers. You can, for example, start them 4 minutes after network-up, or set the timers to run at a standard time during lunch, or whatever you want that meets your needs.

Comment: Interesting detail about the systemd changes. The problem is that the network is often unavailable when `cron`or `anacron` runs. Currently using a `network-manager` dispatcher script to get network stuff done after connecting. Disappointing that the OS cannot handle this rather common situation.

Comment: Major rewrite to address the new second question.

Comment: Tried the `systemd` approach, not practical because the `target`s AKA runlevels, including network-up, are only run once per boot. Network-manager trigger works for every network-up. Noted for irrelevance of `cron`, take it to mean `systemd` timer. Still not clear how to ensure packages are updated when running `unattended-upgrade` manually, without resorting to `apt update` in the script, in which case might as well admit failure and do `upgrade` as well.